# Meaning of phrase 「友情タッグで経験値一杯」

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm trying to figure out the meaning of 友情タッグで経験値一杯 in the following sentence. And how does it connects to the latter part.

> 「えぇもう、こっとんとは友達ですよ。親友の域までいつ到着してもおかしくないくらいです。そうしたら、**友情タッグで経験値一杯**、ますます部活に精が出るってなもんです」
>
> 「あれ、琴子も同じ部活だったんだ？」
>
> 「いや、そういうわけじゃ無いですけど、気分の問題です。ハンペンと同じですね。キブンは大事でおいしいです！」

The way I can understand this passage -
"And when we do(become a best friends), we'll put more and more efforts to the club activities, getting lots of experience points from friendship tag, or something like that(ってなもんです).".

Not sure if it is a good way to translate ってなもんです, but I hope it reflects the meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dialogue made me lol in post-midnight.

友情タッグで経験値一杯 is likely to be a reference to some kind of video game, such as [パワプロ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jikky%C5%8D_Powerful_Pro_Yaky%C5%AB_series), where you can [gain extra XP boost by training with high friendship characters](http://pawapuro.xyz/archives/201506130035/) (タッグ means "tag-teaming"). The connection to other parts are quite loose because of the colloquial nature, but you can consider it as a sentence adverbial.

ってなもんです here can be rephrased as というものです, but maybe difficult to find a meaningful English translation anyway. It's something like intensifier such as "that's what I call" or "for sure".

A very, very loose translation might be like:

> ...Once we do, we'll go archon mode and power overwhelming, more and more energy to club activities, you bet!

By the way, [ハンペン](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanpen) in the last line is a kind of [surimi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surimi), so that キブン has a double meaning of 気分 and [紀文](http://www.kibun.co.jp) (a major company producing surimi).

Comment: Wow, キブン was really unexpected... 

Thanks very much for the explanation.